# Getting error using iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

This is for my `iCarouselViewController.m`

```
- (void)dealloc
    {
        //it's a good idea to set these to nil here to avoid
        //sending messages to a deallocated viewcontroller
        carousel1.delegate = nil;
        carousel1.dataSource = nil;
        carousel2.delegate = nil;
        carousel2.dataSource = nil;

        [carousel1 release];
        [carousel2 release];
        [items1 release];
        [items2 release];
        [super dealloc];
    }
```

I am getting an error saying

> 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode
>  ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
>  
>   'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode
>  ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
>  
>   'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode
>  ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
>  
>   'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode
>  ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
>  
>   ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'

and error in this code aswell

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)] autorelease];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds] autorelease];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    else
    {
        label = [[view subviews] lastObject];
    }
```

saying

> 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode
>  ARC forbids explicit message send of
>   'autorelease'
>   'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in
>   automatic reference counting mode
>   ARC forbids explicit message
>   send of 'autorelease'

How can I clear this error.
**Update**
Thank you for the answer I just have 4 error saying use of undeclared identifier imageArray1.  and I know that this is happening. I just don't get " I assume you are just using app's bundle and we have two arrays of NSString which refer to each image: imageArray1 and imageArray2." Below is one of my save code and creating directory for one of my directories. Note: I have only one NSMutableArray called allImagesArray which I have declared in the header file.

```
NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple",nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

    for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder

        NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tops"];            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
        time_t unixtime = (time_t)[[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldTopsImage.PNG",unixtime];
        NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:timestamp];
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

**Update 4**
ThiS?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure carousel


    imageArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"apple";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];

    NSArray * directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray1 = directoryContent;

    imageArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *location=@"green";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray2 = directoryContent;
```

Comment: You are saving the images in your sandbox.
Retrieve each image path(that would be in NSString) and create an imageArray1 with these strings, to load images in carousel1 and accordingly create imageArray2. See my edit to understand how to load those images from the retrive paths and show in iCarousel

Comment: Sorry I am getting mixed up about the imageArray1 and imageArray2.  In my case I don't think I have to arrays.

Comment: See I created two arrays coz you mentioned two carousels. Now how would you load the images into two carousels from a single array? if you want to use single array, you either have to say that in the array first ten images are for Carousel1 and all other images are for Carousel2.This does not seem practical to me. So I created two arrays. The thing to learn is how to create these two arrays from the image paths. As I said you need to learn and understand NSFileManager for that case. Its not difficult, you just need to keep pushing, keep learning.

Comment: Can you see my question? Do you mean this?

Comment: Exactly. So you are almost there. Dont alloacte/initialise imageArray1. Just do this :
imageArra1 = directoryContent;

//Repeat Steps for imageArray2
location=@"green";
    fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray2 = directoryContent

Comment: Am I almost there!?! I have updated question, getting few errors and warnings

Comment: See, I would suggest you read Apple Docs and start learning from a simple project. The errors are all basic and can easily be rectified. You just need to apply yourself more. This way is not an ideal way to learn. You have now enough base in this problem to solve it by yourself. You must post questions on StackOverflow only if you are sure you have done enough to solve your problem, and still not found the solution.

Comment: Yes I did and I know what the error means but if I follow what you said in the instructions it becomes like this especially you said repeat steps...

Comment: When I said Repeat steps, i also provided you code and in that code I never declared those variables again.

Comment: OK its getting messed up.  I did what you asked look at my question again.  You said that the code provided saying that it wond be declare again.  It obviously is since I am getting redefinition error.  As you say in the upper comment I have been learning objective-C and I KNOW THAT IT IS REPEATING AND THE MEANING OF REPEATING ASWELL.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an `iCarousel` issue. You are using statements like `release`, `autorelease` in your code. Remove it. In ARC you do not need to do memory management manually. That is why ARC is there.

**UPDATE:**
According to your comments, you are facing problems in displaying images for Mutiple Carousels.
I assume you are using two iCarousel objects. lets name them `carousel1` and `carousel2`.
 Also, it seems you are using sandbox for saving images. If this is the case, then you have to fetch images from your sandbox using `NSFileManager`. You need to keep looking at how to do that, but the code for iCarousel will remain more or less same in that case as well. Here, for simplicity case I assume you are just using app's bundle and we have two arrays of `NSString` which refer to each image: `imageArray1` and `imageArray2`.

In `viewDidLoad`, set `delegate` and datasource objects of each carousel as `self`

```
    carousel1.delegate = self;
    carousel1.dataSource = self;
    carousel2.delegate = self
    carousel2.dataSource = self;
```

Implement datasource methods accordingly:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //return the total number of items in the carousel
    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        return [imageArray1 count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [imageArray2 count];
    }
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];

        UIImage *image;
    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
         image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:index]];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
    }
    else
    {
       image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray2 objectAtIndex:index]];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
    }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Very simply, you just need to avoid sending the messages that the compiler is warning about.

Comment: Of-course the issue can be solved using a compiler flag to tell Compiler that this file does not use ARC. But, in my view if you are using ARC in some of the files and non-ARC in some of the files, then this is more confusing and more difficult to maintain code. We must follow one approach only. If the issue had been because of a library compiled in NON-ARC then it would have been wise to use compiler flag, but here the issue is just because OP is using code with release/autorelease.

Comment: Thanks, every thing was cleared but I can't find the place where you import the pictures to the Carousel since I will be importing from my app directory and displaying into two Carousel.

Comment: If the images are stored in the app bundle then just create an array with their names and use viewForItemAtIndex method. Replace this line :  ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"]; with
((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[createdArray objectAtIndex:index]];

Comment: Sorry For asking many questions. new in carousel. I have saved my photo in a sub directory in side the directory.  Of course I have created an Array for it. However I want to assign on sub directory for the top and a different sub directory for the bottom. I have used your code and nothing is happening.  I have no errors.

Comment: Top and Bottom is not cleared. Are you using Multiple Carousels? I am assuming by directory and sub directory you mean groups in your Project's workspace where you have saved images, right?

Comment: I am very sorry that I forgot to mention that I am using Multiple Carousels.  I have placed two in the view controller like the demo.  and I mean sub directory as the directory of the IOS device.I have created about 6 folders in the directory folder so that I can save the taken pictures.   I have saved few.png files in there.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is actually really easy, you have ticked the "Use Automatic Reference Counting" (ARC) box when creating your XCode project. To solve it just go to your target, (iCarousel I assume) and do this "buldsettings" ---> objective-c automaticrefcount :NO

The compiler should then work. What ARC does is do this stuff automatically for you, so you don't have to write auto release and release statements, but if you need them do what I suggested. Otherwise remove these release and autorelease statements.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're using ARC in your project and the code you showed here doesn't. To disable it in those classes add `-fno-objc-arc`. You can do so by going into the targets Build Phases tab. In Compile Sources group, double-click the file (class) and add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag.

Or you could just remove all release messages.

Comment: Who says iCarousel don't? I am using its 1.7.6 version and it does support ARC.